# how to get coordinates of words in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to find the coordinates (x,y) value of all words in html. I have tried to add `<span> for each word </span>` and find using

```
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()
```

above is working fine. But my question is, how can i get the position of words without wrapping the words with additional tags as mentioned above ? or is it possible to do so ?

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element) about retrieving the position (X,Y) of an HTML element might be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelHurley - Thank you for sharing the link, above link will work if i wrap the text with some html tag.

Comment: Ah I see your meaning now thanks for the clarification. I do not believe that javascript is capable of finding the coordinates of text content inside of elements.

Comment: @MichaelHurley -  Yes i am trying with Jquery, still no solution